# vuex state wasn't loaded in nuxtjs mounted() after hard-reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, persistent-storage

I've been building my first app in nuxtjs but I have some issues with vue state.
I've integrated `vuex-persistedstate` and `js-cookie` to persist the state.

I'm trying to get the vuex state and set the values in the component inner state (`data () {}`).

```
Notification.vue

computed: {
   ...mapState({
     user: state => state.auth.user
   })
 },
mounted() {
  this.notifications = this.user.notification
}
```

This is working fine if I come to this page from the other page.

But if I reload the notification page directly, this.user(vuex state) is `null`.
if I wrap it in `setTimeout()`, I'm getting the state correctly even after the reload the page.

for example:

```
mounted () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.notification = this.user.notification
  })
```

I believe this is async issue with vuex & nuxtjs but I don't think it's a good idea to wrap the setTimeout in all components mounted() method.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you get `state.auth.user` via an asynchronous request?

Comment: I believe so since I've got the user in setTimeout correctly. fyi, this is an issue on hard-reload in nuxt.js. after the initial load, it's working fine without setTimeout as I navigate the pages.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I fixed it using `this.$nextTick()` instead of  `setTimeout()`. I think it's a bit cleaner.